# taxonomy_select_nodes with date range - drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

Im using `taxonomy_select_nodes` to get all the nodes by passing taxonomy id. I need to get nodes between specific range. Is it possible to pass date range to this function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You can find the function here in the drupal 7 codebase: `modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.module`

If you look at the function, it doesn't allow for any alternate queries.

You can copy this function into your custom module and rename it, such as "mymodule_select_nodes_by_date", then change the query logic and input parameters.

```
function mymodule_select_nodes_by_date($tid, $pager = TRUE, $limit = FALSE, $start_date = "", $end_date = "", $order = array('t.sticky' => 'DESC', 't.created' => 'DESC')) {
  if (!variable_get('taxonomy_maintain_index_table', TRUE)) {
    return array();
  }
  $query = db_select('taxonomy_index', 't');
  $query->addTag('node_access');
  $query->condition('tid', $tid);


  if($start_date != "") {
    $query->condition('t.created', $start_date, '>=');
  }

  if($end_date != "") {
    $query->condition('t.created', $end_date, '<=');
  }


  if ($pager) {
    $count_query = clone $query;
    $count_query->addExpression('COUNT(t.nid)');

    $query = $query->extend('PagerDefault');
    if ($limit !== FALSE) {
      $query = $query->limit($limit);
    }
    $query->setCountQuery($count_query);
  }
  else {
    if ($limit !== FALSE) {
      $query->range(0, $limit);
    }
  }
  $query->addField('t', 'nid');
  $query->addField('t', 'tid');
  foreach ($order as $field => $direction) {
    $query->orderBy($field, $direction);
    // ORDER BY fields need to be loaded too, assume they are in the form
    // table_alias.name
    list($table_alias, $name) = explode('.', $field);
    $query->addField($table_alias, $name);
  }
  return $query->execute()->fetchCol();
}
```

This would expect unix timestamp input, for example:

```
$data = mymodule_select_nodes_by_date(20, FALSE, FALSE, 1330970202, 1375200837);
```

If you wanted to use differently formatted date input, you could use any of php's date manipulation functions to take formatted dates and then convert them to unix timestamp before querying.

Comment: Seems like a good example. But i've written a custom query according to my need. I'll definitely try this one too, as my query take a bit more time to load.